# Reduce method os array of objects with a condition: is a number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array:

```js
const products = [
    { product: 'banana', price: 3 },
    { product: 'mango', price: 6 },
    { product: 'potato', price: ' ' },
    { product: 'avocado', price: 8 },
    { product: 'coffee', price: 10 },
    { product: 'tea', price: '' },
  ]
```

And Iwould like to sum all prices. What I tried:

```js
const sum = products.reduce(function(acc, cur){
if (Number.isInteger(cur.price))
  return acc+cur.price

  }, 0)
 console.log(sum)
```

it returns undefined. I also tried that without the condition, it returns a string. Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: You forgot to declare `products` in the second snippet. Also, the first snippet is unnecessary; just use a code block if your code doesn't have any output.

Comment: You need a return for `else` also

Comment: Return the accumulator after the if-condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the accumulator if the condition is not `true`.

```js
const
    products = [{ product: 'banana', price: 3 }, { product: 'mango', price: 6 }, { product: 'potato', price: ' ' }, { product: 'avocado', price: 8 }, { product: 'coffee', price: 10  }, { product: 'tea', price: '' }],
    sum = products.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
        if (Number.isInteger(cur.price)) return acc + cur.price;
        else return acc;
    }, 0);
    
console.log(sum);
```

A shorter approach adds the value conditionally and returns only the accumulator at the end.

```js
const
    products = [{ product: 'banana', price: 3 }, { product: 'mango', price: 6 }, { product: 'potato', price: ' ' }, { product: 'avocado', price: 8 }, { product: 'coffee', price: 10  }, { product: 'tea', price: '' }],
    sum = products.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
        if (Number.isInteger(cur.price)) acc += cur.price;
        return acc;
    }, 0);
    
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const products = [
    { product: 'banana', price: 3 },
    { product: 'mango', price: 6 },
    { product: 'potato', price: ' ' },
    { product: 'avocado', price: 8 },
    { product: 'coffee', price: 10 },
    { product: 'tea', price: '' },
  ]

const sum = products.filter(x => typeof x.price === 'number').map(x => x.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of your accumulator for the last element tea is `undefined` because you don't return anything, if `price` is not a number. And as this is the last call to the accumulator, also the result of `reduce` is `undefined`.

If you just want to ignore values with invalid price, you can either use

```
products.filter(x => Number.isInteger(x.price)).reduce (...)
```

to only sum up products with a valid price

or return for instance `acc` if  `cur.price` is not a number.

```
const sum = products.reduce(function(acc, cur){
  if (Number.isInteger(cur.price)) 
    return acc+cur.price;
  return acc;
  }, 0)
 console.log(sum)
```